# EF6 Code First : Data Seeding with self reference

Tags: c#, entity-framework, seeding, .net-4.8

**Goal**
Having a root record in my table, which references itself as its parent.

**Background Info**
I usually work with EF Core, so everything is pretty straight forward using

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Type>().HasData(...);
```

However I can't seem to get it to work with EF6 Code First.
Unfortunately I cannot migrate to EF Core, since the project is targeting .NET Framework 4.8 (which I am not able to change).
The code provided below unfortunately doesen't work as I was hoping it would.

**Model**

```
[Table("PS_CONTAINERS")]
public class PasswordContainer
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public DateTime DateModified { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public int? ParentContainerId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ParentContainerId")]
    public PasswordContainer ParentContainer { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PasswordContainer> ChildContainers { get; set; }
}
```

**DbContext**

```
public class SqlDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<PasswordContainer> Containers { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PasswordEntry> Passwords { get; set; }

    public SqlDbContext(string connectionString) : base(connectionString) {
        Database.SetInitializer(new CobraDbContextInitializer());
    }
}
```

**Initializer**

```
public class SqlDbContextInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<SqlDbContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(SqlDbContext context)
    {
        // add default container without referencing itself
        var defaultContainer = new PasswordContainer()
        {
            Id = 0,
            DateCreate = DateTime.Now,
            DateModified = DateTime.Now,
            CreatedBy = "System",
            ModifiedBy = "System",
            DisplayName = "System"
        };
        context.Containers.Add(defaultContainer);
        context.SaveChanges();

        // get it again and update it with reference to itself
        var addedContainer = context.Containers.Find(0);
        addedContainer.ParentContainer = addedContainer;
        context.SaveChanges();

        base.Seed(context);
    }
}
```

Comment: Your data model seems to allow the parent to be null - why not use that to mark the root element? (That also ensures you never end up with unbounded recursion if navigating up and failing to check if you've reached the root)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Working with a nullable property was just another attempt to get it to work. Somehow it feels... wrong to me, working with null as root element. It feels like there's a better (or correct ) way to do it. But you would suggest just going with null to mark my root element?

Comment: Most implementations of tree structures that I've seen have used `null` as the `Parent` to indicate the root node. It is a VERY common and well-understood pattern. On the other hand, I've personally never worked on a project where `Parent` pointed to its self as a flag for the root. I would find it very confusing.

Comment: @BradleyUffner Understood. Then I'll adapt this pattern. Thank you good sire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by @Damien_The_Unbeliever & @BradleyUffner, having an object reference itself indicating it is the root object is actually not the suitable way.

It is a well known pattern to have the parent set to `null` as indication for the root element.